Google Cloud Monitoring Alert Policy: an incident is not created until 30 minutes have passed after the threshold is exceeded
I am creating an alert to send email notifications when response_code_class != 2xx occurs. However, despite configuring the conditions as below, there is a 30-minute lag between the response and the incident creation, resulting in the email being sent 30 minutes later.
Does anyone know how to create the incident and send the email immediately after the occurrence? I would greatly appreciate your advice.

metric: Consumed API - Request count
filter: response_code_class != 2xx
        service = vision.googleapis.com
        project_id = my_project
Rolling window: 1 min
Rolling window function: max
Condition Types: Threshold
Alert trigger: Any time series violates
Threshold position: Above threshold
Threshold value: 0
Retest window: No retest
Incident autoclose duration: 30 min

I tried changing the values of the Rolling Window and Retest Window in various ways.
I was expecting the email to be sent immediately after at least one response_code_class != 2xx occurred, but the result remained the same.
